# model.sel in MuMIn package error with gamm or uGamm models of betar family

Tags: r

I have fit 2 models separately using `gamm` with betar distribution and then tried to use `model.sel` in `MuMIn` package to build a model selection table.  As seen below, `model.sel` runs into an error.

```
>m1<-gamm(y ~ x1+ (x2, k=5), family=betar(link="logit"),random=list(Time=~1), data=myData)
>m2<-gamm(y ~ x4+ (x5, k=5), family=betar(link="logit"),random=list(Time=~1), data=myData)

>model.sel(m1,m2)
Error in get(x) : object 'Beta regression' not found
```

I am ware that I can simply run these within `dredge` but I would rather fit them separately before combining them to a model selection as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `model.sel` doesn't work with models using "extended.family" from **mgcv**. As a temporary workaround you should make the family name a name of a callable function (as in e.g. `gaussian()$family == "gaussian"`), so in case of `betar` that would be:

```
 `Beta regression` <- betar
```

If you use other types of "extended.family", you can use the function to do the above for you:

```
workaroundExtendedFamily <-
function(family.function, family.object = family.function(...), ...) {
    ff <- sub("\\(.*", "", family.object$family)
    if(!exists(ff, parent.frame())) assign(ff, family.function, parent.frame())
}
```

Examples:

```
  workaroundExtendedFamily(betar)
  workaroundExtendedFamily(ocat, theta = 1)
```